# Three runners start at different speeds, two at 7:00am, one a 7:01am

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Three runners called them Tom, Dick and Harry run along a circular route.
Tom takes 5 minutes to complete a round, Dick takes 7 minutes, and Harry takes 11
minutes. Tom and Harry start their run at 7:00 am sharp, but Dick fills his water
bottle first and starts at 7:01 am. After how many minutes, minimum, will they
complete a round at exactly the same time?

I know I could compute this without too much difficulty by listing the times at which Dick and Harry complete a lap and finding their first shared multiple of 5 ( since Tom has a period of 5 and started at 7:00am, this would also be the first time he shared with both Dick and Henry).

However, I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to find the solution, perhaps involving congruences?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Answer (score 2):

When this event happens after $N$ minutes the three will have completed $t$, $d$, and $h$ rounds respectively, and one has the equations
$$N=5t=7d+1=11h\ .$$
This at once implies $t=11x$ and $h=5x$ for some $x>0$, hence 
$$N=55x=7d+1\ .$$
In particular $55x\equiv1$ mod $7$, and as $55\equiv-1$ mod $7$ we necessarily have $x\equiv-1$ mod $7$ as well. Therefore the smallest admissible $x$  is $x=6$, so that we obtain $N=330$ [min] as solution  of the problem.